# Compare multiple values in a single column oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, comparison

I want to compare multiple values of a column with a single value of another column.I had tried a lot but it gives me "No row selected" 
here's my scenario...

I have a table **Bus_stop_table**:

Bus_ID(FK) ------STOP_ID

201 -------------------401

201 -------------------402

201--------------------403

202 -------------------401

202 -------------------405

203 -------------------403

203 -------------------406

I have to choose a bus_id who has both stop_id 401 and 403. which is 201
but when i try to find this I didn't get the desired result..
here's my queries

```
SELECT BUS_ID,stop_id FROM BUS_STOP_TABLE WHERE STOP_ID =all(401,405);
```

and

```
SELECT BUS_ID,stop_id FROM BUS_STOP_TABLE WHERE STOP_ID 401 and STOP_ID = 
405;

SELECT BUS_ID,stop_id FROM BUS_STOP_TABLE WHERE STOP_ID 401 and STOP_ID = 
405 group by (bus_id , stop_id);
```

Please anyone can help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Group by` and `Having` clause

```
SELECT Bus_ID
FROM   Bus_stop_table
WHERE  STOP_ID IN ( 401, 403 )
GROUP  BY Bus_ID
HAVING Count(DISTINCT STOP_ID) = 2
```

or more flexible approach

```
SELECT Bus_ID
FROM   Bus_stop_table
GROUP  BY Bus_ID
HAVING Sum(CASE STOP_ID WHEN 401 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
       AND Sum(CASE STOP_ID WHEN 403 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
```